# How do I get the relative file path of an image or video?

Tags: html, image, frontend, editor, filepath

Each time I try to add an image to visual studio code I keep having to inspect and get the entire image source code.

I would like to just use /images/down-chevron.png.

Any help?
Thanks!

Example of my code:

```
 <img src="file:///C:/Users/tashe/Downloads/CODING%20CAGES/Cleant%20Dental%20services/images/up-chevron.png" id="upArrow" onclick="upArrow()">
 <img src="file:///C:/Users/tashe/Downloads/CODING%20CAGES/Cleant%20Dental%20services/images/down-chevron.png" id="downArrow" onclick="downArrow(
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the images you'd like to use in a folder called img inside of the folder where your HTML and css live. Then for the img tag in the HTML you could use something like

```html
<img src="./img/down-chevron.png">
```

The ./ lets you navigate through the working tree. Using ../ would go back two directories if needed.

Comment: I learned so much from this. I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Just replace the "file:///C:/Users/tashe/Downloads/CODING%20CAGES/Cleant%20Dental%20services" with a dot from the src attribute and you'll be good to go.

```
 <img src="./images/down-chevron.png" >
```

In VS Code, depending on your autocomplete settings, each time you write src, should give you options for autocomplete including the images folder.